# Is there any straightforward way of knowing that a tempered distribution can be represented by a continuous function?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

According to [this](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erbm/iml/Chapter1.pdf) pdf, the "Schwartz representation theorem" says that for any tempered distribution $u \in \mathcal{S}^\prime(\mathbb{R}^n)$ there exists a finite collection $u_{\alpha\beta}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ of bounded continuous functions, $|\alpha|+|\beta| \leq k$, such that

$$
   u = \sum_{|\alpha|+|\beta| \leq k} x^\beta D^\alpha_x u_{\alpha\beta}.
$$

My question is: is there some straightforward criterion for knowing when this representation reduces to its trivial form, and $u$ can be simply represented by a bounded continuous function, without any derivatives? Are there any "hallmarks" of such distributions? In my specific context I know that the distributions obey a linear first order PDE, if that helps!

Comment: $n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}\ast u$ is bounded and converges locally uniformly

Comment: Thank you, seems obvious now I've been told! Just to make sure I understand: that convergence happens as $n \to \infty$, and it's true by virtue of $\{ne^{-\pi n^2 x^2}\}_n$ being a sequence  of approximations to the identity?